# Não envia email recuperação de senha pelo SendGrid

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sendgrid

Implementei uma classe para envio de e-mail de recuperação de senha, porém o email não é enviado.

Código classe envia email:

```
public static Task EnviaEmail(string email, string assunto, string mensagem)
    {
        var MinhaMensagem = new SendGridMessage();
        MinhaMensagem.AddTo(email);
        MinhaMensagem.From = new MailAddress("meuemail", "meunome");
        MinhaMensagem.Subject = assunto;
        MinhaMensagem.Text = mensagem;
        MinhaMensagem.Html = mensagem;
        var credenciais = new NetworkCredential("meunomedeusuario", "minhasenha");
        var transporteWeb = new Web(credenciais);

        if(transporteWeb != null)
        {
            return transporteWeb.DeliverAsync(MinhaMensagem);
        }
        else
        {
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Quais os testes feitos? Fez em um servidor neutro? Verificou se não foi considerado spam? na forma atual parece que a não temos sequer como saber se é um problema de programação. Você tem que fornecer informações suficientes para garantir que o problema pode ser resolvido por nós aqui ou só você pode resolver. Pode ser que seja problema de programação e nem estar nesse trecho. Já fez um [mcve]?

Answer (score 2):

[Esta versão do seu código não trabalha com credenciais](https://sendgrid.com/docs/Integrate/Code_Examples/v2_Mail/csharp.html). Ao invés de passar usuário e senha (como no método antigo), passe diretamente a API Key.

Tente também implementar [este outro exemplo](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-csharp#with-mail-helper-class), mais orientado à nova arquitetura de serviços do SendGrid:

```
    public static Task EnviaEmail(string email, string assunto, string mensagem)
    {
        string apiKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings['SendGridApiKey'].ToString();
        dynamic sg = new SendGridAPIClient(apiKey);

        Email from = new Email("naoresponda@seusite.com.br");
        Email to = new Email(email);
        Content content = new Content("text/plain", mensagem);
        Mail mail = new Mail(from, assunto, to, content);

        dynamic response = await sg.client.mail.send.post(requestBody: mail.Get());
    }
```

Comment: No site do sengrid nao está habilitando para eu poder gerar uma key, nao sei o motivo, tem algum outro jeito ?

Comment: Eu acho que não. Não achei mais exemplos com autenticação por credenciais.

Comment: Portanto tem um problema, se o seu usuário cadastrar um email outlook ou hotmail ele não irá receber nada na caixa de mensagens dele, pois o email fica como bloqueado, por conta disso estou tentando achar uma outra ferramenta que substitua o Sendgrid!

Comment: @WPfan Acho que seria o caso de reportar o problema ao SendGrid.